# Reuse of adhoc distribution profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile

Is it possible to reuse adhoc distribution profiles and certificates which are created for another ios app in my ios application or Do i have to create new ones to distribute my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use Adhoc certificate and profile for another ios app , but should mention a same app identifier.

You can test your app on device using this profile and certificate.

But at time of AppStore Submission, you should have a seperate profile for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are not specific to an application. Ad Hoc provisioning profiles are tied to a particular app however, and can only be used for a single app.